# Im not able to create Gpt-4 deployment

Tags: azure, openai-api

I am trying to use gpt4 right now and yes i have the access but im not even getting a chance to use it
Am u doing something wrong, trying to figure out why im not even getting an option for this.

I want to get this sorted.

Comment: Hi can you confirm which region are you using for this?

Comment: Please provide more detail. What do you mean by "use"? Are you trying to programmatically access it via an API? Access it through its regular user interface? And what happens when you try? You just say "I'm not getting a chance to use it", which tells us **nothing** about what problem you're experiencing.

Comment: Hi mohamed im usinh east us region

Comment: Daniel im not getting an option to select gpt4

Comment: @NiveedhaM gpt4 enabled by ms only on eastus2 regions. Create a new instance on eastu2 where you can create gpt4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess it is currently not available in east us and we can except it to drop soon sorry we don't have any specific date on which its going to be available.

for more information please find the link below.

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/concepts/models#gpt-4-and-gpt-4-turbo-preview

Comment: May i know when it is available for east us region? Whats the solution where can i see what regions ot supprts

Comment: I have given a documentation link plz go through it and u can find which is available whrere